# How do I add quotes, commas, and spaces after each word in a ms-word list?

Tags: javascript, java, python, html, arrays

I am trying to add quotes and a comma after each word in a word document.

```
For example:

apple
banana
carrot

Goes into:

"apple",
"banana",
"carrot",
```

What should I put in the find section and replace section to arrive at this outcome?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just do this in ms-word?

Comment: ?? You give nothing towards any real information.  First thing that comes to mind is Why? Second thing is, what `find section and replace section`? In what application, MS-Word or your own application? Most importantly however is, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

On `LibreOffice Writer` you can press `CTRL + H` to open the find and replace tool.

You must enable regular expression and configure as following:

Find: `(\w+)`

Replace: `"$1"`

And then press replace all.

I am sure you can do it on ms-word as well.

[image: LibreOffice Writer]

Comment: Further to vmf91, in ms word it is similar. Use keyboard short cut ctl-h to open the find and replace window, in 'Find what:' put in  ------->     ^p     to search for paragraph breaks and in the 'replace with' put in   ----->  "^p"           to replace the found paragram mark with quotes and a new paragraph mark.  You'll have to put in the first quote and delete the last extra quote.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have both JavaScript and Java tags in your question, but I will assume you meant Java. A possible solution to what you want to do using Java:

1) Lets first read in the file with the words and create a way to write out the result:

```
String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("path-to-input"))); // input
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("path-to-output")); // output
```

2) We've read the contents of the file as a single String, lets split it now into individual words. We will do this by splitting by carriage return and newline (depending on your file, only newline may be sufficient):

```
String[] splitContents = contents.split("\r\n");
```

3) Let's change the Strings in the array above to the ones that we want to see in our file. Then output them to file:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < splitContents.length; i++) {
        splitContents[i] = "\"" + splitContents[i] + "\","; //create new string
        writer.write(splitContents[i]); //write new string to file
        writer.newLine(); //append newline
    }
```

4) And don't forget to `flush()` and `close()` the `writer`:

```
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```